# view not update with 2 module angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have three module app.root , app.shell , app.shop . And it like that

```
.module('app.root',['app.shell,'app.shop'])
```

In app.shop , I add item in cookies

```
vm.add = function(tensp,gia,img){
                     var item = {
                    tensp : tensp,
                    gia   : gia,
                    img   : img
                  };

   var cart = $cookies.getObject('cart');

      if (cart) {
        var items = JSON.parse(cart);
             items.push(item);

        $cookies.putObject('cart', JSON.stringify(items));
      } else {
        $cookies.putObject('cart', JSON.stringify([item]));
      }
```

In app.shell, I display it in html

```
      vm.cookies = JSON.parse($cookies.getObject('cart'));
 {{vm.cookies.length}}
```

This problem is view not update . It only update when I refreshing the page . Where is my wrong . Please help me

Comment: Hi again, please add your full view and controller.

Comment: Hi . When I create a plnkr , karim has solved my problem . But thank for hi me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't post the whole code but trying to guess the problem i think you should watch the cookies array for any change, fetch the new value and then update the view.

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
 return $cookies.cart; //watch the cart array
}, function(newValue) {
  vm.cookies = JSON.parse(newValue);
}, true);
```

In your code you're only fetching the data once, keep in mind that the cart array is a copy of the original one, not a reference.

```
vm.cookies = JSON.parse($cookies.getObject('cart')); //this is a copy of the array
{{vm.cookies.length}} //view
```

Comment: Well, I was making a plunker to answer him. But you were faster, here is the plunker anyway : https://plnkr.co/edit/gkmFeHCMkMCBVgDDrGJs?p=preview

Comment: hope it will fix his problem ;)

Comment: Many thank . I will try it . Here is my plnkr i create https://plnkr.co/edit/hsb8AT6jaBY07fgC2gFS?p=preview